# Play Framework - How to maintain configuration files for different environments?

Tags: deployment, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, config-transformation

For my [Play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/)/Scala application (built with SBT), I would like to deploy different configuration files depending on the environment I'm deploying to (e.g. to couple a deployment with a particular database server). How does one create different variants of the application's configuration file (conf/application.conf) for different deployment targets? Hopefully variants can be generated from a base version?

What I'm used to from .NET is to have a base configuration file (Web.config), which undergoes a certain transformation depending on the profile one is deploying (e.g. Production). Does one use a similar technique in the Play/Scala world?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**Alternative configuration files**](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration) are covered in Play's documentation quite well in section `Specifying alternative configuration file`.

In short - in `application.conf` you place default configuration of your app, and additionally you need to create additional files for you environment(s) ie. `life.conf`, `dev.conf` etc. In these files you first need to include `application.conf` (which will read whole default configuration) and next just overwrite **only** parts which have to be changed - ie. DB credentials, it could be `dev.conf`:

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:alternative-database-for-dev-testing"
db.default.user=developer
db.default.password="developerpass"
```

So finally you start your application (after `dist`) as

```
./start -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf
```

or with the Play console

```
play -Dconfig.resource=dev.conf run
```

Several tips:

- It's good idea to do **not** place your 'life' DB credentials in default `application.conf` file, if some dev will forget to include his `dev.conf` he won't damage the production DB, instead you should put it in `prod.conf`.
- Also these additional configs shouldn't be placed in any VCS (ie. git) repository - creating them directly on target machine (and ignoring in repository) give you sure, that people who shouldn't know the life database credentials won't see it.
- It's also possible to use remote alternative config file, which can be useful ie. when you deploying several instances of the same app ie. on several hosts in the cloud.
- Each dev can has own config file ie `dev_aknuds1.conf`, `dev_biesior.conf` etc, so you can ignore them with one pattern `dev_*.conf` in repo.
- Finally you can just create a shell script (unix) or bat file (Windows) to start using choosen config file like `start_dev.sh`, `run_dev.sh` etc. so you won't need to write `-Dconfig.resource=...` each time

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say how to generate configuration file variants, which is the core problem here.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what biesor just described to you? Include will base a config file on another only overriding the settings you want to be different.

Comment: @johanandren The answer has been expanded since I first commented. I also see now that the 'include' technique is mentioned in the documentation; it's easy to spot now that I'm aware of it, I wish it were more obvious for someone new to Play... All in all, this does look like a great solution.